# stored procedure SQL exasol

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, while-loop, exasol

I've a table with huge data and it needs to be break down into chunks and passed to the insert query.
I need to write a stored procedure for this
Logic for the stored procedure is drafted out like this (can be improved too):

```
VARIABLE= SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TABLE1
RUN_LOOP= (VARIABLE / 10) +1
COUNTER = 1
start= 0
END_ALL =1000

BEGIN
   WHILE @COUNTER <@RUN_LOOP
       SELECT * FROM TABLE2
       WHERE RN BETWEEN @start+1  AND @END_ALL 
     
    COUNTER = COUNTER+1
    @start=END_ALL + 1
    @END_ALL = END_ALL+1000

END
```

How loop values should change:

```
VARIABLE    RUN_LOOP    COUNTER start    END_ALL
3125           4           1      0      1000
3125           4           2      1001   2000
3125           4           3      2001   3000
3125           4           4      3001   4000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Lua script. See the documentation [here](https://docs.exasol.com/7.0/database_concepts/scripting.htm).